# How do I use this PS script?

Tags: powershell

I have several PS script files that were created to do things. The trouble is that I don't know exactly how to use them to pull the information I need from them or to make the changes the script is supposed to make. When I right-click and run with PowerShell I get a PS window open briefly and then close. In the code below I want to pull the OS versions of multiple computers on the domain and have it list the version along side the computer name.

It would mean that I would not have to go visit every machine to reimage a lot of them if I knew what version of Windows they have on them.

Does anyone want to work with a newbie and show me how to use the PS file to make this happen?

```
.SYNOPSIS
Get SDC version from USAF computers.

.PARAMETER ComputerName
Specifies the computers to query.

.PARAMETER IncludeError
Optional switch to include nonresponding computers.

.INPUTS
None. You cannot pipe objects.

.OUTPUTS
System.Object

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-SDCVersion

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-SDCVersion -ComputerName PC01,PC02,PC03

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-SDCVersion (Get-Content C:\computers.txt) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-SDCVersion (Get-Content C:\computers.txt) -IncludeNonResponding -Verbose |
Export-Csv SDCVersion.csv -NoTypeInformation

.NOTES
Author: Matthew D. Daugherty
Date Modified: 2 August 2020

#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param (

    [Parameter()]
    [string[]]
    $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [Parameter()]
    [switch]
    $IncludeNonResponding
)

# Scriptblock for Invoke-Command
$InvokeCommandScriptBlock = {

    $VerbosePreference = $Using:VerbosePreference
    
    Write-Verbose "Getting SDC version on $env:COMPUTERNAME."

    $Path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation'

    [PSCustomObject]@{

        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        SDCVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path).Model
    }
} 

# Parameters for Invoke-Command
$InvokeCommandParams = @{

    ComputerName = $ComputerName
    ScriptBlock = $InvokeCommandScriptBlock
    ErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
}

switch ($IncludeNonResponding.IsPresent) {

    'True' {

        $InvokeCommandParams.Add('ErrorVariable','NonResponding')

        Invoke-Command @InvokeCommandParams | 
        Select-Object -Property *, ErrorId -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId

        if ($NonResponding) {

            foreach ($Computer in $NonResponding) {

                [PSCustomObject]@{

                    ComputerName = $Computer.TargetObject.ToUpper()
                    SDCVersion = $null
                    ErrorId = $Computer.FullyQualifiedErrorId
                }
            }
        }
    }
    'False' {

        Invoke-Command @InvokeCommandParams | 
        Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunspaceId
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered contacting Matthew D. Daugherty? It sounds like you're not familiar with Powershell so you shouldn't really attempt to run scripts which you don't know what they do. But to be fair, that scripts includes example usage anyway.

Comment: Save it as *Get-SDCVersion.ps1* in any directory. Then, navigate to the directory and run it like `.\Get-SDCVersion`. It says SDC for USAF and I work with them as well, well USSF. Do you have MS Teams, and I can help you out there with other stuff as well, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Zinala. My email is otis.skinner.ctr@us.af.mil, my teams account shows "SKINNER, OTIS K CTR USAF AETC 82 TO". I'd love to get this solved. I can put together a list of all of the computers to use but frankly I moved on to the rest of my work and forgot about this question. My apologies sir. Thank you, I'd love to learn how to do this.

Comment: Mr. Zinala, I do have an ongoing issue with a revision of the Pratt & Whitney quarterly CD's (CD 17 and CD 17), I get. When I try installing (CD 16 ),from the shared drive, I am getting two errors when the .exe package attempts to launch the "incremental_art.bat" file and the update_driver.bat file that comes with the CD's in the Utilities folder.

Comment: I suspect it is happening because the software is written as if you are installing it from the CD. I am installing it from a shared network drive so I'm guessing I need to find the config.ini file that calls these two files and adjust the path. But I am having no luck finding that sorce file. Any insight would help me a lot I'm sure. I will reach out on Teams Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this by just opening a PS Window, and running the script from there instead of running the script file.

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Computer Accounts,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=more,DC=stuff" -filter * -properties operatingSystem  | Select-Object Name, operatingSystem | export-CSV \Domain\shares\Temp\Computers.csv -notype

Open a PS Window first if you want the output to stay in the Window, and then take off the "| export-CSV \Domain\shares\Temp\Computers.csv -notype" so that the output isn't redirected.

Comment: This is going to give conflicting results if the domain contains member computers that have been in-place upgraded

Comment: Josh, that is very good information, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the Powershell window opens and closes immediately, it means that there is an error or that the script has finished its execution.
You can add at the end of the script **Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key...."** or you can open a Powershell window, you go to the folder (with **Set-Location -Path "....."**), then you execute the script **.\my-script.ps1**

Comment: Damien, that's really good information, I can't wait to try that out. Thank you.